# One tapRecognizer for several imageViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have several `imageViews` and I want to add one `tapRecognizer` for all `imageViews`.

So I know how to add `tapRecognizer`.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTapped:")
imageViewOne.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

It works, but I also want to add this for rest like

```
imageViewOne.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
imageViewTwo.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
imageViewThree.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
imageViewFour.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer) 
...etc
```

But here the `imageTapped` method will work only for the last one.

Question is: is it possible to do it not creating new `tapRecognizers` for each `imageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Its not possible with 1 **TapGesture**. You need to create separate `tap gesture` for each image view, even you can set same target method for all `tap gesture`.

If you are going to create several images with tap gesture then you need to make a separete method and create each image view with tap gesture in **for** loop.